# How to make the child object to match the location and rotation of parent object

Tags: transforms, parent

I have 2 objects : A and B. A will become the parent object, it has position/rotation animation. B is static object (no animation) . I want the B to be the child of A so i want B to move/rotate exactly as A ... but also i want to be able to move B in its local coordinate. This is like regular parenting, but i want B to jump to A and match A orientation.

Comment: Are you trying to animate the transition from the untransformed B to the transformed B?

Comment: A has animation ( A can be an empty object) i want to parent B to A so B (child) will have the same movement /rotation/scale etc as A (parent) while B can still have its local indendent movement.

Comment: It sounds like regular parenting will do the job, unless you want to animate the "jump" where B enters A's reference frame. In that case, you could use a "Child Of" constraint on B, targeting A, and animate the influence property of the constraint from zero (off) to one (on).

Comment: As Justin says, you can easily do what you want to do with simple parenting: parent B to A, create some keyframes for the movement of A, create some keyframes for B when you want it to come closer or go away from A, where exactly is the limit of this simple method?

Comment: Thanks i already got the answer below, so when i clear out/reset position/rotation of B to 0, it should jump to A as if the A position is the 'world' of B.

Comment: yes but by default A will be the world of B, if you select B and press alt G, B will stick to A, is it not what you want?

Comment: if i press alt G,  yes .. B will stick to A , but in one condition, when parenting the A (parent) has to be in (0,0,0) . If A not in (0,0,0) when parenting , then press alt G won't make B to the center of A. The fact is my A is animated so it's in arbitrary position.

Comment: The trick i used to do is to add temporarty keyframe and set A pos/rot/scale to 0 then do the parenting. After that i will delete this keyframe.

Comment: oh ok I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use child of constraint and press alt G (alt R resets the rotation) to Reset the location of object B.
[image]

Comment: This way, i can't move/rotate B anymore.

Comment: if you want to still be able to transform the mesh use the child of constraint

Comment: nice, it works perfectly. Btw how can i bake this constraint if i want to export to fbx ?

Comment: i know very little about animation so i can't help you with that you should post another question.

Comment: Ok no problem , thanks a lot for the solution.